# Android-volley: how do I take the String response value and assign it outside of a volley StringRequest method?

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

The data appears as expected when I run the method in the debugger, however whenever I try to do anything with it the value of parentObject is returned as null.

I simply want to take the response from the server and store it as a JSONObject to be reused elsewhere.

```
public void jsonParse() {
    String url = "http://178.128.166.68/getUserInfo.php";

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,  new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                /*
                the data appears as expected within the debugger however
                 returns null when i attempt to use it elsewhere
                 */
                parentObject = new JSONArray(response);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("phone", phone);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }
    };
    mQueue.add(request);


}
```

Comment: first check your JSON type is JSONArray or JSONObject

Comment: JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);

Answer (score 0):

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,  new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
            parentObject = new JSONArray(obj);
            for (int i = 0; i < parentObject.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject parObj = (JSONObject) parArray.get(i);
                ModelClass modelClass = new ModelClass()// you have to create a model 
                modelClass.set1Parameter(parObj.getString("1Parameter"));
                modelClass.set2Parameter(parObj.getString("2Parameter"));
                arrayList.add(modelClass)//In your arraylist save the data


            }



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to check what type response you getting from server i.e (JsonObject or JsonArray).

```
public void jsonParse() {
    String url = "http://178.128.166.68/getUserInfo.php";

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,  new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                /*
             if its JSONObject
                 */
                  JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(response);
                String  value= jsonobject.getString("value");


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("phone", phone);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }
    };
    mQueue.add(request);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

as per your question ... you want to store response in jsonObject but in code you are store response in jsonArray

> parentObject = new JSONArray(response);

so you must have to confirm response is in object or array.
if response is in object (like {}) change to `parentObject = new JSONObject(response);`
else change type of parentObject to `JSONArray`